# How to use purrr map with columns from a dataframe?

Tags: r, purrr

I want to divide multiple columns of a dataframe by a column of that same dataframe (to get percentages). I would like to do it with purrr, to be able to iterate the operation for each column, and I tried to do it in the following way, but failed.

```
#create the tibble
competitor_a <- c(125,300,250)
competitor_b <- c(321,452,366)
competitor_c <- c(231,271,139)
data <- tibble(competitor_a,competitor_b,competitor_c)
data <- data %>% 
  mutate(total_sales=sum(competitor_a,competitor_b,competitor_c))

#iteration 

data %>% 
  map(select(competitor_a,competitor_b,competitor_c)/total_sales))
```

where `data` is my dataframe, `competitor_a, competitor_b, competitor_c` are columns with the sales of the competitors (dividend), and `total_sales` are my divider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case I think it is better to use `across` :

```
library(dplyr)
data <- data %>% mutate(across(competitor_a:competitor_c, `/`, total_sales))
```

This can also be done using base R :

```
data[1:3] <- data[1:3]/data$total_sales
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `total_sales` column is incorrect. Because you're summing across rows, you need to do the following (using `dplyr`):

```
data <- data %>% 
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(total_sales = sum(c_across(everything())))
```

As for the map, one way is to use an anonymous function:

```
data %>%
  map_dfr(~.x/data$total_sales*100) %>%
  select(-total_sales)
# A tibble: 3 x 3
  competitor_a competitor_b competitor_c
         <dbl>        <dbl>        <dbl>
1         9.23         23.7        17.1 
2        14.7          22.1        13.2 
3        16.6          24.2         9.21
```